# How to get the MouseEvent.localX and localY of a target but not its child objects?

Tags: flash, events, actionscript, drawing, coordinates

I'm creating a simple drawing application that adds new Shape objects to a MovieClip "canvas" every time the user clicks and drags.  The problem is, I'm noticing that even though the MouseEvent listeners are set to the MovieClip, the child Shape objects are being returned as targets as well.  This disrupts the localX and localY as well, causing the drawing cursor to jump around as the coordinates change from being local to the entire MovieClip to local to the Shape the mouse is currently over.

Is there any way to retrieve the most parental target from a MouseEvent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you maybe simply wanna set `DisplayObjectContainer::mouseChildren` to `false` ... other than that, you can the `currentTarget`, which should be your `MovieClip` and use its `DisplayObject::mouseX` and `DisplayObject::mouseY` ... or you could use the `MouseEvent::stageX` and the `MouseEvent::stageY` and then `DisplayObject::globalToLocal` to transform it to your `MovieClip`'s coordinate space ...

little sidenote: why `MovieClip` and not `Sprite`?

**edit:** the actual point, why i don't like using `MovieClip` is, that it's dynamic, so you get no compiler errors on typos ...

greetz

back2dos

Comment: The canvas does additional stuff that requires a movieclip.  However, I may simply fact that out and use a sprite instead.  All in all, one clip isn't going to hurt too much in terms of performance.